# Cannot find implementation for Room Database using Kotlin Gradle DSL

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am having difficulty adding the Jetpack Room library to my Gradle Kotlin DSL project. I've modified the Room implementations steps from the [Room documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room), and run into this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.igorwojda.showcase.feature.news.cache.NewsDatabase. NewsDatabase_Impl does not exist`

Below is everything I have tried so far. First, are the dependencies inside a feature module file, `feature_news.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions

apply(plugin = "kotlin-kapt")
// plugins{}, android{}, etc
dependencies {
    implementation(project(ModuleDependency.APP))

    addTestDependencies()

    api(LibraryDependency.ROOM_RUNTIME)
    kapt(LibraryDependency.ROOM_COMPILER)
    api(LibraryDependency.ROOM_RX_JAVA)
}
```

The references to `LibraryDependency`:

```
    // LibraryVersion.ROOM = "2.0.0"
    const val ROOM_RUNTIME = "androidx.room:room-runtime:${LibraryVersion.ROOM}"
    const val ROOM_COMPILER = "androidx.room:room-compiler:${LibraryVersion.ROOM}"
    const val ROOM_RX_JAVA = "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:${LibraryVersion.ROOM}"
```

Finally, the database and entity are very simple

```
@Database(entities = [CachedNews::class], version = 1)
abstract class NewsDatabase  constructor() : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun cachedNewsDao(): CachedNewsDao
}

@Entity(tableName = NewsConstants.TABLE_NAME)
data class CachedNews(
        @PrimaryKey var id: String, val text: String, val createdAt: String, val sinceId: String
)
```

Comment: It feels like either the Room compiler is not running or it is not putting its output in the expected place. Search your `build/` directory for your module and see if you can find any sign of the generated code there.

Comment: @CommonsWare somehow things are working and I have no idea how. I did check the `build` dir and saw both the dao and db `_impl` files. The only thing I changed between the failed and successful builds was formatting for posting on Stackoverflow. Thank you!